# What is a de Vries algebra?

Tags: duality

I've come across a set of [slides](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hap/GuramBezSlides.pdf) by Guram Bezhanishvili where he claims the category of compact hausdorff spaces is related by duality to de Vries algebras. What are they?

Comment: Google finds http://staff.science.uva.nl/~gfontain/tacl09-abstracts/tacl2009_submission_61.pdf which contains a definition. 

Answer (score 3):

See his article "Stone duality and Gleason covers through de Vries duality" in Topology and its Applications 157:1064--1080, 2010, Definition 3.2.